# Conseguir un grupo de números menores a 250 como variable

Tags: java

Que tal tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un botón conectado a un JTextField(en este caso textfieldvel1), que cuando lo completás con un número menor a 250 te diga mal, y cuando ingresás un numero mayor a 250 te diga bien por un JTextArea. mi problema real es que no puedo hacer andar el algoritmo, lo del JTextarea después lo veré, pero si alguno tiene una mejor idea. estoy intentando crear como variable esta secuencia:

```
   int numerosmenoresa250= for(int i=0;i>250;i++)             
   {
    System.out.println("funciona bien");
    }else{
      System.out.println("funciona mal");
    }
```

sin embargo no me la toma e intuyo que no lo hace porque no puede ser variable. Debe ser una tontería porque recuerdo haber hecho cientos de estos ejercicios cuando arranqué hace varios años, sin embargo me trabé.

```
      Object obj= e.getSource();
            if(obj.equals(botonvel1))
            {
                    if(textfieldvel1.getText().equals(numerosmenoresa250<250)) //"En este paréntesis pretendo poner la condición de menor a 250."
                {
                System.out.println("bien");
                enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad mínima correcta -\n");
                }
                else{System.out.println("mal");
                enunciado.append("- Velocidad mínima incorrecta -\n");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas un solo valor. No necesitas un `for` a menos que desees tener un `Array`. Ahí si sería válido.Por ejemplo una colección de 30 enteros ingresados por teclado

```
     int[] valores = new int [30];
     for( int i=0;i<30;i++)
      { 
          valores[i] = Scanner.nextInt();
      }
```

En el botón agregar algo así. Hacer el `cast` del `Text` devuelto por el `getText`  para luego realizar la comparación

```
  if(Integer.parseInt(textfieldvel1.getText().trim())<250)
   {
     System.out.println("Bien") ;
     /* append a tu TextArea */
   } 
   else{
      System.out.println("Mal") ;
       /* Append a tu TextArea */
   }
```

El método `trim()` es para eliminar los espacios a los costados. por si acaso después de ingresar 4 das en un espacio en el JTextField sin querer. con ese método elimina dicho espacio. Es un método para las cadenas en general.

Comment: la verdad esa misma la pensé, pero crei que no era necesario usar parseInt, osea siempre que se quiera cambiar de un JTextfield a nnumero hay que usar parseInt?

Comment: Y no, creo que no necesito más de un valor a ingresar, porque la idea es que sólo puedan ingresar un dato al jtextfield, asi que intuyo que sólo será un dato.

Comment: Exacto. Dependiendo del uso que le quieras dar. Dado que el método `getText()` devuelve una cadena y al hacer una comparación sería `if("4"<25)` donde 4 en formato cadena es lo que ingresas al JTextField   y eso no se puede dar. Ahí está el detalle de hacer el cast. O conversión

Comment: Funcionó excelente, era más facil de lo que me imaginaba, gracias, ya van dos me solucionaste.

Comment: Ahora entiendo, getText() siempre te devuelve con "caracteresconquotes", una ultima pregunta, vengo colocando trim.() pero no sé para que sirve, es la última y no molesto más.

Comment: No molestas. Es bueno ser curioso así se aprende. El método `trim()` es para eliminar los espacios a los costados.  por si acaso después de ingresar `4` das en un espacio en el `JTextField` sin querer. con ese método elimina dicho espacio. Es un método para las cadenas en general.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes meter en una variable `int` más de un número entero. Debería ser un array. No obstante te recomiendo parsear la entrada y hacer una simple comparación:

```
int valorMetido = -1;

try{valorMetido = Integer.valueOf(textfieldvel1.getText());} catch/Exception e){}

if(valorMetido <= 250 && valormetido >= 0){
    System.out.println("bien");
    enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad mínima correcta -\n");
}
else{System.out.println("mal");
    enunciado.append("- Velocidad mínima incorrecta -\n");
}
```